# How would I repeat content on pages (and modify some) in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to figure out how to place content across pages as well as modify only some of the "same" things.

For example, I have two services. Let's say I want to add a small box on the right panel. On the pages directly under the root of my site (Home, About Us, Contact Us), I want this box to contain generic information (We provide services for . . . ). On the pages related to service one (the service one page and sub-pages), I want that same box to contain pretty much the same text except changing it specific to service one (Our service one solution...). The same for service two and it's sub-pages (Our service two solution...).

To change content I think I'd be right to leave "Make a Copy" checked. However, I don't want this box to appear on every page, just one's that I choose (whether grouped or not; i.e. root pages, service one pages, service two pages).

How can I accomplish this? I'm working directly using the DNN 7.01 admin/host interface - I'm imagining I can accomplish this by creating separate .ascx files, but for this I think it defeats the purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: If you change one version, do you want that change reflected in all of the other versions as well?

Comment: @DanielGimenez Not in all instances. If I had 3 groups (root/service one/service two), changes in the root box should propogate, but not affect the other two. I'm almost kicking myself that I say that because I guess I could just have 3 boxes specific to the groups. Sorry, coming from Orchard where I use layers to accomplish this. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you will want to do is use the "Add Existing Module" function to handle this.

For example for the content that you want to be the same, add it to the "main" page and setup the content.  Then on the pages that need to have THAT version use "Add Existing Module" and add the module from the "main" page.

Then, when you have a variation that is to be shared across other pages, repeat this process.

DO NOT use the "Display On All Pages" option though as more than likely that will trash things!

Answer (score 1):

I've not a lot of experience as Mitchel, and his answer seems the way to go. But as an alternative (when dealing with LOTS of modules with static content), I found using a template page with all the modules (and content within) helps to group things so that you can use that template for sub pages that have the same content. In other words, only the actual content pane for a sub page needs to be created because you are copying all the other "widgets" you have on your page.